# Search an arraylist containing class for a specific item name

Tags: java, class, search, arraylist

I have a class as:

```
public class Test_Demo{
    public String name;
}
```

Now i have an arrayList as:

```
public ArrayList<Test_Demo> tdArrayList= new ArrayList<Test_Demo>();
```

Now I create an object of above class as and add it to Arraylist:

```
Test_Demo td = new Test_Demo();
td.name="Hello";
tdArrayList.add(td);
```

Now I compare the name as:

```
String testname="Hello";
for(int i=0;i<tdArrayList.size();i++){
    if(tdArrayList.get(i).name.equals(testname)){
        //name present, print here and break from loop
    }
}
```

This works fine, but if the **ArrayList has many items, this method is slow**. Can you suggest me of any better approach?
tdArrayList.contains(testname) wont work because arrayList doesn't have names but it has class that in turn has the name.

Comment: without checking inside, iterating all over, I don't think it is possible to check a specific variable into a series of objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Search an arraylist containing class for a specific item name

There is no way out to see from outside **if**  **any** class, having that name or not.

You have to iterate and see.

Comment: Well is there any way i can avoid looping entire list? I mean sort list may be alphabetically according to name first and then search ? Will that improve the searching?

Comment: No, What you are doing is good. There is no side effects. Even though you search on some part of String, Even though you have to iterate. I think you need not to worry about time. It takes negligible amount of time to iterate.

Answer (score 1):

In general terms, this is the best approach. But if you want to improve efficiency, then you may make clusters of ArrayList, such as ArrayList storing names starting with 'A', 'B' and so on. Then if test name is 'Hello' then, get its first letter 'H' and search in the cluster 'H'. You may increase number of clusters depending upon your need. This might be a one solution.

Comment: this will take more storage space na? Space time tradeoff !?

Comment: It takes same storage for the names, and little addition is information about the clusters. Will definitely advantage on performance over space.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure of the context. But try answer using hashmap by mapping name and object.

Comment: I think this may be useful, but I will have to change the existing data structure ! Will try it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First overrride `equals` method in your `Test_Demo` class and then use ArrayList `contains` method.

Answer (score 0):

Override `equals` method  like following:

```
public class Test_Demo{
   public String name;
   public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
      if (this == anObject) {
         return true;
       }
     if (anObject instanceof Test_Demo) {
        Test_Demo test = (Test_Demo )anObject;
        if(test.name.equals(this.name)
           return true;
      }   
      return false;
   }
}
```

And then call `contains` method.

Comment: isn't this doing the same way as I am? and I feel that this may take more time !

Answer (score 0):

How many items in the tdArrayList? And how long does it take you to iterate the whole list?
Maybe you can sort the list,and then binary search.